# Poul Anderson short story about sentient dolphin-like race with green blood

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space, poul-anderson

I'm looking for the name of a Poul Anderson short story (written prior to 1979). The short story involves a lone space traveler who finds a planet inhabited by a dolphin-like race. He befriends the species, but after doing research on what would happen if more humans come, he begins killing them. One detail I remember is that their blood was green.

I really appreciate the help. Thank you!

Comment: To make sure that they will treat humans with caution, in case another human ship arrives

Comment: That's one way to do it, I guess....

Answer (score 10):

That is *Sister Planet*,  See wiki article at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sister_Planet

> Although it is decided not to continue with the terraforming project, and even to destroy the research before it can be reported to Earth, Hawthorne knows what he must do to stop a repeat of the research by others. He sabotages the colony, leaving no-one alive but him, and shoots many cetoids [including one whom he has befriended and nicknamed Oscar] , to make them distrust and fear humans. As he recognizes Oscar's dead body, he thinks to himself "Oh God. Please Exist. Please make a hell for me."

He notices that Oscar's blood is green.

Comment: This is great, an Anderson story I've never read! This is why I like story id questions.  Sounds like a downer of a story though...